# Call typescript function in html table in <td> tag without click event

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to call function that are in typscript file in my html table in td tag between span tags.
This is the function ts side:

```
  importoWithIVA() {
let totconIva = 0;
if (this.movRighe.id !== null) {
  totconIva =
    this.movRighe.quantita *
    this.movRighe.prezzo *
    ((1 - this.movRighe.sconto1 / 100) * (1 - this.movRighe.sconto2 / 100) * (1 - this.movRighe.sconto3 / 100)) *
    (1 + this.intCodiciIva.aliquotaIva);
}
return this.twoDecimal(totconIva);}
```

From html side i have to call that function. I tried with the code below but doesn't work. I'm new in angular so I don't know if this way is right or not.

```
'td><span>{{importoWithIVA()}}</span></td>'
```

Someone could give me an answer? Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. append more code 2. don't call function in```{{}}```

Comment: More code ts or html?

Comment: You should append both

Comment: dont call functions inside html for performance,

Comment: I add mor code.

Comment: You need to compile typescript code to javascript and then use it in html.

Comment: I don't have to use javascript. It is not foreseen in the work that has been assigned to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out the basics of angular and how it works. You can not call a function like that in the template. What you can do is assign a value to a variable in the ts file and output this value to the template.

```
let totconIva = 0;
if (this.movRighe.id !== null) {
  totconIva =
    this.movRighe.quantita *
    this.movRighe.prezzo *
    ((1 - this.movRighe.sconto1 / 100) * (1 - this.movRighe.sconto2 / 100) * (1 - this.movRighe.sconto3 / 100)) *
    (1 + this.intCodiciIva.aliquotaIva);
}
this.myVariable = this.twoDecimal(totconIva); // here you assign a new value for a variable.
}

'td><span>{{this.myVariable}}</span></td>'
```

Since this in a `td` I have the suspicion that oyu need to do this for multiple rows, in this case you need an array of variables where you calculate the value for each row and then output the variable's content in a `*ngFor` loop.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Your directive was useful. Anyway yes i have more field to fill with the result of different function. I have wrote only this because i have to do in the same way for the other fields.